# How to check Palindrome in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

To check palindrome I am using `REVERSE` function of SQL Server.

I wanted to check how reverse function works with this sample code:

```
declare @string nvarchar
set @string = 'szaaa'
SELECT REVERSE(@string)
```

But the output was 's' in case of 'aaazs' which I expected. How should I capture the reverse? Is there any better way to find palindrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, *always* use lengths with the character types:

```
declare @string nvarchar(255);
set @string = 'szaaa';

SELECT REVERSE(@string);
```

The default length varies by context.  In this case, the default length is "1", so the string variable only holds one character.

Answer (score 3):

To check palindrome, You can use CASE Statement

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(255);
SET @string = 'szaaa';

SELECT CASE WHEN @string=REVERSE(@string)THEN 'Is palindrome'
            ELSE 'Is not palindrome' 
            END
```